# RegularExceptionValidator created via code

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, validation

I'm trying to do validation with the regex class and a custom RegularExceptionValidator created when a submit button is pressed.
The regex and the regular expression work fine.
My problem is that the Validator doesn't appear in my page:

```
                RegularExpressionValidator revTel = new RegularExpressionValidator();
                revTel.ErrorMessage = "Le format Tel: ";
                revTel.IsValid = false;
                revTel.ValidationGroup = txtPhone.ValidationGroup;
                Validators.Add(revTel);
                revTel.Visible = true;
```

**Update:**
Thanks for your answers.
The missed code is:

```
revPhone.ControlToValidate = "txtPhone";
```

I forget to assign a Control to Validate to the validator.

**Update**:
I was wrong :/!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (e.Exception.InnerException is OptimisticConcurrencyException)
        {
            var concurrencyExceptionValidator = new CustomValidator();

            concurrencyExceptionValidator.IsValid = false;
            concurrencyExceptionValidator.ErrorMessage =
            "L'enregistrement que vous essayez de mettre à jour a été " +
            "modifié par un autre utilisateur après que vous l'avez récupéré. " +
            "Les nouvelles valeurs sont affichées.";

            concurrencyExceptionValidator.Visible = true;
            concurrencyExceptionValidator.Enabled = true;

            concurrencyExceptionValidator.Display = ValidatorDisplay.Dynamic;

            Page.Validators.Add(concurrencyExceptionValidator);

            concurrencyExceptionValidator.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
```

### PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(concurrencyExceptionValidator);

```
            //Page.Controls.Add(concurrencyExceptionValidator);


            e.ExceptionHandled = true;

        }
```

I've added a placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

Add below line to your above code, hope this works

```
Page.Controls.Add(revTel);
```

Comment: When i do that an exception is raised: the validator should have runat="server". How could i do that within c# code?

Answer (score 0):

You called `Validators.Add(revTel)`. Possibly it should be added as child control:

```
divValidationControls.Controls.Add(revTel);
```